# NuGet -ConfigFile option supersedes %ProgramData% config file

Tags: nuget

According to the NuGet documentation, you should be able to specify a custom config file while still using any additional config files that are located in %ProgramData%\Nuget\Config. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. If I specify a custom config file, any config file I have in %ProgramData% is unused:

C:\> nuget.exe sources

(output includes sources specified in my %ProgramData%\Nuget\Config\A.config)

C:\> nuget.exe sources -ConfigFile B.config

(output includes sources specified in B.config but not in ProgramData%\Nuget\Config\A.config)

As a matter of fact, if I specify the -ConfigFile option, I can even put xml errors in A.config and it doesn't complain at all.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I re-posted this at the NuGet site, and it looks as if there was an intentional change in behavior in version 3.4.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2812